# Jquery function is working just on first element, I want to work on all classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've created a Jquery function that looks like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var animations = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-up');
for (var i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var elementTop = animations[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementVisible = 140;

    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
        animations[i].classList.add("active");
    }
    else {
        animations[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
}});
```

The problem is, it is working just on the first class when I'm scrolling down, I want to work on each class.I also try something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
$('slide-up').each(function($) {
    var animations = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-up');
    for (var i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var elementTop = animations[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var elementVisible = 140;

        if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
            animations[i].classList.add("active");
        }
        else {
            animations[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
    }
});});
```

But with same results.Any ideas or suggestion about how to apply to all elements that have .slide-up class when I'm scrolling down ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example:  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the error of your 2nd code might be in the 2nd line: it should be $('.slide-up')

Comment: Well, thanks, this is a step forward but still as the Twisty's aswer, It work just on the first element with the class '.slide-up'.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var animations = $('.slide-up');
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var elementVisible = 140;
  animations.each(function(i, el) {
    var elementTop = $(el).position().top;
    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
      $(el).toggleClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

This should perform an action on each element. All code has been switched to jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still It works just for first element with the class. ".slide-up"

Comment: Also I've mentioned I want the class active to be added when I m scrolling , I've founded a solution to add class active to each .slide-up element, but the class "active" is added after refreshing/ entering on the page. I want to be when viewport is on that element.The new code is in the next comment.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready( function($){
 $('.slide-up').each(function(i, obj) {
  var animations = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-up');
  document.querySelectorAll(".slide-up").forEach((el, idx) => {
   var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
   var elementTop = animations[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
   var elementVisible = 140;
   if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
    $(el).toggleClass("active");
    console.log('not new')
    $(el).removeClass("active");
   }
   else {
    $(el).toggleClass("active");
   }
    });
 });});

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example